# Extract the word before a matched word Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Hello I am trying to extract the word before a matched word in Python.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
data = [' 123 DIR FOOD CITY','124 DIR DRINK CITY','143 STREET CANDY CITY','186 ROAD APPLE CITY']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['ADDR'])
```

I am trying to extract the words 'FOOD', 'DRINK', 'CANDY', and 'APPLE'.
My desired output is:

```
ADDR                        CITY
123 DIR FOOD CITY           FOOD
124 DIR DRINK CITY          DRINK
143 STREET CANDY CITY       CANDY
186 ROAD APPLE CITY         APPLE
```

This is what I tried but it yields nothing.

```
df['CITY'] = df['ADDR'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(re.findall(r'(\w+)\s+CITY',x)))
```

I am not very good at using regex, what is wrong with my code?

Really appreciate your help!

Comment: Can you explain the conditions for matching? What does _it yields nothing_ mean, exactly?

Comment: I ran it and it is the desired output. did you try printing df?

Comment: @asafpr what i get is, all the rows are ' FOOD, DRINK, CANDY, APPLE'

Comment: @AMC it gets the word before the word 'CITY'. the result is ' FOOD, DRINK, CANDY, APPLE' for all rows, not nothing, sorry.

Comment: _it gets the word before the word 'CITY'_ Is it always the third word, or always the second to last one? _the result is ' FOOD, DRINK, CANDY, APPLE' for all rows, not nothing, sorry._ Which means it's working, no?

Comment: Also, can you be more specific about what you're struggling with?

Answer (score 0):

Use `extract` and regex:

```
df['CITY'] = df['ADDR'].str.extract('.*\s(?P<CITY>.*)\sCITY')
```

Output:

```
                    ADDR   CITY
0      123 DIR FOOD CITY   FOOD
1     124 DIR DRINK CITY  DRINK
2  143 STREET CANDY CITY  CANDY
3    186 ROAD APPLE CITY  APPLE
```

Another way using rsplit with n=2,

```
df['CITY'] = df['ADDR'].str.rsplit(' ', n=2).str[1]
```